# How can I list different method using a good opening word for my sentences

Tags: sentence-structure

I would like to write about different methods. I need to write them in a good English way. I tried to use "one" and "another" but do not know if this is a correct structure or not?

**My short paragraph**:

*One existing method is a method A introduce by author C. Another method is the one introduced by author D. Their method is simple and fast. Another method was introduced by E.*

In the last two sentences, I used the word, "Another". So, I feel that I just repeat the opening word of my two sentences. By the *opining word* I mean *One* and *Another*.

How could I list different methods in a paragraph in a good English structure? any help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want "good English structure", you should look for ways to avoid repitions of words when possible. I would write your paragraph something like this.

> There are three existing methods. One, method A, was introduced by
>   author C, another simple and fast method by author D, and a third by E.

In my version, I used a technique called "parallel structures". The type of construction I used is called a "list", and I employed "serial commas". I suggest you look up those terms in grammar books. It is possible to write grammatically correct English without using them, but until you understand how they work your results will tend to sound awkward and unnatural.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Yes, what I really need to is learning about "parallel structures". As a learner, it is the first time for me to hear about this topic.

Answer (score 2):

You’re right: using “another” multiple times like that would be awkward. “One method...a second method...a final method” could add the appropriate variety.

Comment: Or "A third method", "A fourth method", etc.